# How to poll simultaneously from stdin and from sockets?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, stdin, polling

I wanted to write a C program that would simultaneously wait for data from `stdin` and from a socket. To achieve this, I wanted to use `poll()`.

But it seems I misunderstood how `poll` works on `stdin`... I expected it to behave just like it behaves on sockets, that is: Report `POLLIN` if and only if I actually typed something in the terminal (and preferably also pressed `RETURN`).

To test if this assumption is correct, I wrote a simple program that `poll`s only on `stdin`:

```
#include <poll.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
  int ret_poll; ssize_t ret_read;
  struct pollfd input[1] = {{fd: 0, events: POLLIN}};
  char buff[100];
  while(1) {
    ret_poll = poll(input, 1, 0);
    printf("ret_poll:\t%d\nerrno:\t%d\nstrerror:\t%s\n",
        ret_poll, errno, strerror(errno));
    ret_read = read(0, buff, 99);
    printf("ret_read:\t%zd\nerrno:\t%d\nstrerror:\t%s\nbuff:\t%s\n",
        ret_read, errno, strerror(errno), buff);
  }
}
```

However, I found that in the above example (when I told `poll` to wait for `POLLIN` on `stdin`) `poll` returns immediately all the time, whether or not I actually type something. Then, of course, the subsequent `read()` on `stdin` blocks. So I guess this means I can’t simultaneously wait from input to the terminal and from a socket :(

Is it possible to make `poll` report `POLLIN` on `stdin` only when there actually is data to read?

Comment: Isn't poll returning immediately because you have the timeout set to 0? Is the return value 0 or -1?

Comment: `{{fd: 0, events: POLLIN}}` is invalid C syntax.

Comment: @Olaf: `{{.fd = 0, .events = POLLIN}}` - better now?

Comment: @Olaf: The fun part is, `{{fd: 0, events: POLLIN}}` works. Tested with `gdb` - all fields of the structure are set correctly. A `gcc` extension, or what?

Comment: gdb is a debugger, how do you use it to compile code?? `fd : ...` is a legacy gcc extension from pre-C99. It has been superseeded by standard designated initialisers and should not be used anymore.

Comment: @Olaf I don't use gdb to compile code of course, I just used it to test if my syntax worked! Thanks for the clarifications about initialisers syntax though.

Comment: A debugger is a bad thing to test C syntax. Use a compiler and read the standard or at least a **good** book.

Comment: `{{fd: 0, events: POLLIN}}` is gcc extension, it was needed before new standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was mentioned above by @Roecrew, `poll()` returns immediately because you gave 0 timeout. As man page said:

> Note  that  the  timeout  interval  will  be rounded up to the system
>   clock granularity, and kernel scheduling delays mean that the blocking
>          interval may overrun by a small amount.  Specifying a negative value in timeout means an infinite timeout.  Specifying  a  timeout 
>   of  zero
>          causes poll() to return immediately, even if no file descriptors are ready.

If you change:
`ret_poll = poll(input, 1, 0);` to `ret_poll = poll(input, 1, -1);` it'll work as you expected.

Comment: Very sorry and very thankful. I did read the man page, but I somehow misread the part about zero timeout. I thought specifying a timeout of zero caused poll to wait infinitely long...